# python requests with application/octet-stream not supported error but succecced in Postman

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

[image]

And here is my python code:

```
  response = session.request('POST', url, data={"quotaionDtos": str(payload)}, files=files)
```

The api call is succecced in Postman and I have the same data in python but failed.